# Getting data from SQLite database to String Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to get information from my database and put it into a string to print it on screen. i thought i could use the code below to do it but it gives out some information about the cursor instead of the information inside the cursor.

```
datasource = new DataBaseHelper(this);
datasource.open();
Cursor c = datasource.getAllGoals();
startManagingCursor(c);
String g = c.toString();
goal.setText(g);
datasource.close();
```

Comment: how information? could you more specificate it? with `String g = c.toString()` you only get `string` representation of `cursor object`.for getting informations from cursor you should use `getters` and method which allow to you passing via data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor can be thought of as a pointer to some underlying data. Running `c.toString()` on the cursor object would print the default `Cursor` class' implementation of its string representation (an at-sign character `@` and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object) which is not what you want.

To retrieve underlying database data, you will need to call `c.getString(columnIndex)` ([source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29)), or whatever column datatype you require for that particular column index.

Here's an example [modified from source](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html):

Say you have created a table

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "create table comments ( "
            + "_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "comment text not null);";
```

and your `getAllGoals` function returns a cursor which points to data about **both** `_id` and `comment`. Now you only want to show the details about the `comment` column. So you have to run `c.getString(1)`. Suppose your `getAllGoals` function returns a cursor which only points to data about the `comment` column. Now you have to run `c.getString(0)`.

I would recommend that you download the source code in the provided example and go through how data is retrieved from a cursor.

**EDIT:**

```
    public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {//retrieve data from multiple rows
            Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
            comments.add(comment);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // Make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return comments;
    }

    private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        comment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));
        return comment;
    }
```

[source](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: what does column index refer to. would i need to change that or is that just what is needed>

Comment: so if i was getting say several bits of information from the database i would run this several times for each bit of information?

Comment: if you mean that getAllGoals returns several pieces of information, you will need to use a while loop. check out my answer again for an updated example.

Comment: note that you will need to know what type of data is being pointed to by the cursor returned by your getAllGoals function. this way, you can call the appropriate getter method on your cursor.

Comment: ok so if it was a get int its getInteger(0); i see. though when i ran the get string it crashed the application

Comment: what does your getAllGoals function look like? what does your underlying table look like? i might be able to help you from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11782/discussion-between-darren-murtagh-and-dhruv-gairola)

Answer (score 0):

```
openDataBase();
Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tb_aa_City where City_Name = '"+cityname+"'", null);
if (c.getCount() > 0) {
    c.moveToFirst();
    seqid = c.getString(4);
    System.out.println("In DB..getSequenceID..."+seqid);
    }
    c.close();
    myDataBase.close();
    SQLiteDatabase.releaseMemory();
```

Comment: how do i get the c.getString(int); to point to the right information

Comment: c.getString(Colomn number) // give database Column number